# OpenLayers MousepositionControl in decimal degree

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers

In my webgis application, we are using OpenLayers 6  with projection 'EPSG:32643'.  I'm using mouse position control to show the mouse position on the map. I want to display the mouseposition in degree decimal rather than meter.

I tried to change the projection inside MousePosition like this

```
   MousePosition({
  projection:'EPSG:4326',
   })
```

But again shows the mouse position in meter.

How to solve this?

Comment: It should work as long as you are using proj4 to define EPSG:32643 https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-irjdj?file=/main.js

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   It works fine in OSM map but we are using our own gis map. Still not working in our map.

Comment: you can try to copy the code from this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mouse-position.html